# Building GEM5 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gem5

Tried GEM5 Simulator installation as per instructions provided in http://learning.gem5.org/book/part1/building.html and by doing the following:

1. sudo apt install build-essential git m4 scons zlib1g zlib1g-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev python-dev python
2. git clone https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5
3. sudo apt-get install python-six
4. sudo scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j2

Went through all available documentation for the build errors ... Not very experienced on C++

The output after the above command is as follows:

> scons: Reading SConscript files ... Warning: Your compiler doesn't
>   support incremental linking and lto at the same time, so lto is being
>   disabled. To force lto on anyway, use the --force-lto option. That
>   will disable partial linking. Info: Using Python config:
>   /usr/bin/python2.7-config Checking for C header file Python.h...
>   (cached) yes Checking for C library python2.7... (cached) yes Checking
>   for C library pthread... (cached) yes Checking for C library dl...
>   (cached) yes Checking for C library util... (cached) yes Checking for
>   C library m... (cached) yes Checking for accept(0,0,0) in C++ library
>   None... (cached) yes Checking for zlibVersion() in C++ library z...
>   (cached) yes Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++
>   library protobuf... (cached) yes Checking for C header file
>   valgrind/valgrind.h... (cached) no Checking for
>   clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library None... (cached) yes
>   Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library
>   None... (cached) no Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL,
>   NULL) in C library rt... (cached) yes Checking for C library
>   tcmalloc... (cached) yes Checking for char temp;
>   backtrace_symbols_fd((void*)&temp, 0, 0) in C library None... (cached)
>   yes Checking for C header file fenv.h... (cached) yes Checking for C
>   header file png.h... (cached) no Warning: Header file not found. This
>   host has no libpng library. Disabling support for PNG framebuffers.
>   Checking for C header file linux/kvm.h... (cached) yes Checking for C
>   header file linux/if_tun.h... (cached) yes Checking size of struct
>   kvm_xsave ... (cached) yes Checking for member exclude_host in struct
>   perf_event_attr...(cached) yes Package hdf5-serial was not found in
>   the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing hdf5-serial.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'hdf5-serial' found Checking for hdf5-serial using
>   pkg-config... no Package hdf5 was not found in the pkg-config search
>   path. Perhaps you should add the directory containinghdf5.pc' to the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'hdf5' found Checking
>   for hdf5 using pkg-config... no Checking for H5Fcreate("", 0, 0, 0) in
>   C library hdf5... (cached) no Warning: Couldn't find any HDF5 C++
>   libraries. Disabling HDF5 support. Checking whether i386 is
>   declared... (cached) no Checking whether x86_64 is declared...
>   (cached) yes Building in /home/murali/GEM5/gem5/build/X86 Using saved
>   variables file /home/murali/GEM5/gem5/build/variables/X86 scons: done
>   reading SConscript files. scons: Building targets ... [ CXX]
>   X86/dev/x86/pc.cc -> .o [ TRACING] -> X86/debug/I8254.hh [ CXX]
>   X86/dev/x86/i8254.cc -> .o In file included from
>   build/X86/dev/x86/pc.cc:41: build/X86/arch/x86/intmessage.hh: In
>   function 'Packet* X86ISA::buildIntTriggerPacket(int,
>   X86ISA::TriggerIntMessage)': build/X86/arch/x86/intmessage.hh:84:44:
>   error: implicitly-declared 'constexpr
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators::BitUnionOperators(const
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators&)' is deprecated
>   [-Werror=deprecated-copy] 84 | return buildIntPacket(addr, message); |
>   ^ In file included from build/X86/sim/serialize.hh:62, from
>   build/X86/sim/eventq.hh:53, from build/X86/sim/sim_object.hh:58, from
>   build/X86/dev/platform.hh:44, from build/X86/dev/x86/pc.hh:40, from
>   build/X86/dev/x86/pc.cc:35: build/X86/base/bitunion.hh:262:9: note:
>   because 'BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators' has user-provided
>   'typename Base::__StorageType
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators::operator=(const
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators&) [with Base =
>   X86ISA::BitfieldUnderlyingClassesTriggerIntMessage; typename
>   Base::__StorageType = unsigned int]' 262 | operator=(BitUnionOperators
>   const &other) | ^~~~~~~~ In file included from
>   build/X86/arch/x86/intmessage.hh:37, from build/X86/dev/x86/pc.cc:41:
>   build/X86/dev/x86/intdev.hh:87:29: note: initializing argument 2 of
>   'Packet* X86ISA::buildIntPacket(Addr, T) [with T =
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators; PacketPtr = Packet*; Addr = long
>   unsigned int]' 87 | buildIntPacket(Addr addr, T payload) | ~~^~~~~~~
>   build/X86/dev/x86/intdev.hh: In instantiation of 'Packet*
>   X86ISA::buildIntPacket(Addr, T) [with T =
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators; PacketPtr = Packet*; Addr = long
>   unsigned int]': build/X86/arch/x86/intmessage.hh:84:44: required from
>   here build/X86/dev/x86/intdev.hh:93:5: error: implicitly-declared
>   'constexpr BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators::BitUnionOperators(const
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators&)' is deprecated
>   [-Werror=deprecated-copy] 93 | pkt->setRaw(payload); | ^~~ In file
>   included from build/X86/sim/serialize.hh:62, from
>   build/X86/sim/eventq.hh:53, from build/X86/sim/sim_object.hh:58, from
>   build/X86/dev/platform.hh:44, from build/X86/dev/x86/pc.hh:40, from
>   build/X86/dev/x86/pc.cc:35: build/X86/base/bitunion.hh:262:9: note:
>   because 'BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators' has user-provided
>   'typename Base::__StorageType
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators::operator=(const
>   BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators&) [with Base =
>   X86ISA::BitfieldUnderlyingClassesTriggerIntMessage; typename
>   Base::__StorageType = unsigned int]' 262 | operator=(BitUnionOperators
>   const &other) | ^~~~~~~~ In file included from
>   build/X86/arch/x86/intmessage.hh:39, from build/X86/dev/x86/pc.cc:41:
>   build/X86/mem/packet_access.hh:62:18: note: initializing argument 1 of
>   'void Packet::setRaw(T) [with T = BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators]'
>   62 | Packet::setRaw(T v) | ~~^ [ CXX] X86/dev/x86/i8237.cc -> .o
>   cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors scons: ***
>   [build/X86/dev/x86/pc.o] Error 1 scons: building terminated because of
>   errors.

Can anyone help me in removing the above errors and in a successful build of the GEM5 simulator build. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you [edit] your post to include a version of the error that retains line breaks? Paste it between 2 lines containing 3 backticks each.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this problem is caused by treating various compiler warnings as errors, when in reality you can ignore them. Go into SConstruct and comment out this function:

```
main.Append(CCFLAGS=['-Werror',
                     '-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations',
                     '-Wno-error=deprecated',
                      ])
```

Alternatively, you can keep adding all the errors you come across to the -Wno-error list, but that would be a bit more tedious.

Comment: Yes, your suggestions worked for me..and could build it successfully.. It had to do with the newer gcc compiler version 9.2.1..Thanks